# Linewidth for plot of a fitted function

Tags: matlab, plot, curve-fitting

I have a problem with my Matlab plot. I have to fit a sin function to the data points I collected. I succeeded, but when I tried to input some parameters (i.e. LineWidth) through a `set` function it always shows an error at the line of the `set` and I don't know why.

Here is my code that works, but when I "activate" the set line it shows an error:

```
 clear all;
 close all;
 C0 = [0]; C1 = [0]; C2 = [0]; C3=[0];
 run('traces3');
 traces3;
 t = datetime ('now');

gri = 0;
filename = 'image.png';
M = [(P(2,1)-P(1,1)), (P(4,1)-P(1,1)), P(1,1);
     (P(2,2)-P(1,2)), (P(4,2)-P(1,2)), P(1,2);
     0,0,1;];
 M2 = inv(M);

 clear tmp1;
 clear tmp2;
 tmp1 = size (C0);
 tmp2 = ones(tmp1(1),1);
 C_0 = (M2*([C0, tmp2])')';
 c0 = sortrows(C_0);
clear tmp1;
clear tmp2;
f0 = fit(c0(:,1),c0(:,2),'sin1');

figure(1)
A0 = size(c0);
a0 = c0(A0(1),1);
h0 = plot(f0, 'b-');xlim([0,a0])
hold on
h_0 = plot(c0(:,1),c0(:,2),'bo');xlim([0,a0])
coul=1;

tit=['File: "',filename,'" ',datestr(t)];
title(tit,'FontSize',20,'Color','k')
f0a=num2str(round(f0.a1,2)); f0b=num2str(round(f0.b1,2)); f0c=num2str(round(f0.c1,2)); 
legend('C0 raw',['F0(x)=', f0a ,'*sin(', f0b ,'x+', f0c ,')'],'Location','southwest')
if(gri~=0)
    grid on
end
%set(h0,'LineWidth', 2) %When I write this line in the code it doesn't work anymore...
hold off

print(tit,'-dpdf')
```

Comment: seems correct. can you provide a complete minimal working example instead of a sample? also please use full code, not inline code

Comment: How about the rest of the error message?

Comment: That is the only error message I got

Answer (score 0):

The plot handle `h0=plot(...)` is an array of handles of ***line*** objects, not figure objects!!!.

Just try for each of the `length(h0)` lines objects at the plot handle vector `h0`:

```
iline=1;
set(h0(iline),'LineWidth', 2);  % This line should work now...
```